# Install dual boot on VivoBook S S510UA

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, asus

After some research for a laptop that may works with dual boot I found VivoBook S S510UA. I must use Windows for work and want Ubuntu for me.
I have some small idea how Ubuntu functions however I could not find clear instructions about the installing process. My biggest concern is buying the wrong computer (not able to handle a partition) and the installing process.

These are my specs:

- Processor Intel® Core™ i7-8550U processor 1.8 GHz 8M Cache, up to 4.0 GHz
- Ram 8GB DDR4
- Graphics Controller Intel UHD Graphics 620
- Hard Drive 1TB 5400 RPM HDD   128GB SATA3 M.2 SSD

Is this the right laptop?
And where can I find the instructions to do the partitioning?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Dual Boot advice:

I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar) and [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/q/221835/)

Answer (score 0):

It is not that hard to install Ubuntu alongside Windows:

- If necessary, install Windows first. Check that the Windows C: partition is not encrypted with Bitlocker. You can use the partition manager of Windows to reduce the C: partition size, if there is no unassigned space on the harddrive (do not touch boot/hidden/reserved partitions).
- Download the Ubuntu installation ISO file, probably the "AMD 64" version (that's for most modern computers). Burn that disk image on a DVD or make a bootable USB-stick. Then boot your computer with it (maybe you need to go into the computer's BIOS/UEFI first, to change the boot order or to disable secure boot). Then your computer should boot Ubuntu from the DVD/Stick. When you select to install it, check the option that says "install alongside Windows". Then it will automaticly create a partition from the unassigned space and install Ubuntu on it. That's it!

If you have good luck, then your computer has only standard hardware and configuration, and you will not run into trouble during the installation process, and everything will work fine afterwards. However, there are so many things that can differ from what Ubuntu can handle, that the only way to find out is to try out yourself or check the web for reports from other users who own the same computer.

Comment: Thank you Shakesbeer for taking the time to write something useful.